# Always open android webview Login dialog when user logged out from my app

Tags: java, android, facebook, webview

[image]

I've integrated Facebook in my app and the user can login, share and post things.   I've implemented a logout also.

Here is my problem: when user wants to log in, the Facebook SDK checks whether the native app is present or not.

- If the native Facebook app is not installed in the user's device then it will open a webview dialog like the image below (First image).
- If the user has the Facebook app, then my app directly asks him/her for permissions without opening the loginUI (Second Image)

[image].

I want to show the Facebook loginUI always.
Each time the user wants to login.

Please help me.

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting. Removed irrelevant thanks

Comment: @Der Golem...Thnks,,!Had any about my question?

Comment: No, sorry. I never used the Facebok API. I just made some seasonal housekeeping. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah i did it....
if anyone in future face this situation this solution may help them
For opening webdialog during login with facebook

If you are using facebook login button,  we need to set the property called as "SessionLoginBehaviour" then write the below code.

```
loginButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

refer [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/SessionLoginBehavior/)

Answer (score 0):

You can check it if facebook installed using this method :

```
private boolean isFacebookExist(){
  try{
    ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().
            getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0 );
    return true;
  } catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: do you know facebook api call...for opening webview login dialog ?

Comment: @gvsharma sorry, i didnt read your comment. are you already solve the issue here?